# Trying to understand octal/hexa

Tags: cryptography

deleted due to unclear question

Comment: Vote to close please

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need octal at all? `fec0ded` is obviously hexadecimal and 8 is either hex or decimal (actually, doesn't matter - it's still the same 8)

Calculations are done as follows:

```
FEC0DED xor 8 (hex)
=
1111 1110 1100 0000 1101 1110 1101 xor 1000 (bin)
=
1111 1110 1100 0000 1101 1110 0101 (bin)
=
FEC0DE5 (hex)
```

I.e. you flip 4th least significant bit.

Comment: This wasn't the answer I was looking for. The problem wasn't that I can't xor the two binaries, my problem was more semanticly issued in the sense that I wasn't sure as to what the semantics behind this was. Never the less I awarded the answer seeing as I have concluded, based on votes to remove this question - as it's very unclear.